# GNOME 3: palm rejection?

Tags: gnome, touchpad, ubuntu-gnome

I have installed GNOME 3 on my Dell XPS 15". Things are going pretty good but the track pad is hypersensitive and has no palm rejection. The slightest waiver over it causes the cursor to move or click. So I was curious as to if there is a way to improve palm rejection.

This other post has yet no answers... [How to fix palm rejection on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931761/how-to-fix-palm-rejection-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Comment: I'm about ready to offer a bounty on this.  It's the most frustrating thing about Ubuntu Gnome these days.  Especially since it used to work fine a few years ago.