# Laptop keyboard gets crazy

Tags: 14.04, keyboard

I run Ubuntu on Dell Inspiron 15, but I have seen this problem in other laptop. When I type faster keyboard cursor jumps in random any place of text. For example title at first attempt was:

```
Laptop keyboardazy  gets cr
```

Why? How to fix that?

UPD: Problem disappeared when I have restarted my Laptop, but I suppose it will be back.

Comment: Perhaps you need to turn on palm detection? https://askubuntu.com/questions/931761/how-to-fix-palm-rejection-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Comment: I don't know what is palm detection, but my touch pad works fine. I have problems with keyboard.